# Choosing a service to associate a timer job with

Tags: timer-jobs

I'm writing a custom timer job in C# and need to pick a service to associate my timer job with. I've tried the local timer service:

```
: base(String.Format(JOB_NAME, Guid.NewGuid()), SPFarm.Local.TimerService, server, SPJobLockType.None)
```

This has been pretty spotty, we've had issues getting this job to run reliably enough on all servers in a farm to be satisfied with. We think this is due to the timer service not updating with the new job sometimes -- clearing the SharePoint config cache and forcing the timer service to update has "fixed" the issue, but we obviously can't use that as a final solution to the issue.

What other services could I possibly associate this job with? I don't want to associate with a web app instead.

Comment: Hi are you wanting the job to run on all servers or just run and you don't mind which server its running on?

Answer (score 1):

I'll presume that you want it to run on all servers.

How about using the following class, Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceJobDefinition.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spservicejobdefinition.aspx

If you continue to use SPFarm.Local.TimerService SPService object, as this service is running on all SharePoint servers this will run the job on all servers.

I have been using this for a while and it seems to work fine.

To answer the question, you can associate to any object that inherits from the SPService class.

As for selecting an SPService, will that depends what you need it to do.
For example you could associate to a Service Application if you wish. The timer job would only execute on the servers that are running the Service Application's Service Instance.

Comment: Interesting -- this doesn't really address the question, but I'll switch my class inheritance and constructor to this and see what happens. I do indeed want to run it on all servers.

Comment: I think you do want to associate it with the Timer Service so that it runs on all servers. However, I have updated the answer to include a further example of a service.

Comment: It's kinda an odd scenario... it's a timer job that runs on all servers and actually provisions a service on that server. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Ah ok - sounds interesting. Is it provisioning a service application or something else like a windows service? Another approach would be using PowerShell. I found this article useful when I was doing Service Applications, http://www.danlarson.com/page/2/

Comment: This did not work as I'm running into the same caching issue with the timer service. This is a cool feature though... I need to find a specific service to associate this job with that I know will be running on any server I want to install my service on. The Timer Service is perfect for this, I dont know what else to use!

Comment: The caching issue? Is this the issue where one or more of the servers get out of sync with the objects in the configuration database and you have to clear out a set of xml files and update a cache.ini file?

Comment: That is EXACTLY the issue and the "fix" we're currently using. We obviously can't have something like that in an actual release of the product. Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: So I think the reason is that if the timer job is running on all servers. Then effectively they are updating the same objects and causing conflicts. Can you post some of your code, are you registering SPServiceInstances on each of the SPServer objects and then Installing a Service Application and Provisioning the service application? You can register/start the SPServiceInstance from one server and also install and provision the service application from that same server too.

Comment: I'm not quite convinced that's the issue. In doing some more testing today, we found that turning the Web Application service on (effectively making it a WFE instead of an App server) allows the job to run successfully. Any idea?

Comment: I have experienced similar problems. In your solution settings in Visual Studio what type of deployment server type have you got selected? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231560.aspx

Comment: What a coincidence, about 10 minutes before you posted that I happened upon that exact page. It turns out that's the issue; the server the timer job isn't running on doesn't have the proper assemblys GAC'd! Not specifying that is SUPPOSED to make the solution a global deployment, but for some reason that's not putting it on the app server. I'm going to specify the app server anyway and see what happens.